# Не корректная работа счетчика

Tags: c#, winforms, события, datagridview

Не могу понять ,почему при работе цикла, результат получается совершенно не тот что я ожидаю.
Предполагается, что при каждом нажатии данные в таблице должны меняться с соответствии с числом на счетчике.

```
       private int count;

    private void SwitchStatus()
    {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            string? status = context.Statuses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Statusid == count)?.Statusname;
            currentStatus = status;
            count = i;

        }

    }
    private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText == "Статус")
        {
            SwitchStatus();
            FilterStatus(currentStatus);
        }

    }
```

[image: Таблица]

Значение перекидывает сразу на индекс = [2]

Comment: Не очень понял что вы сделать пытаетесь, но если вы цикл в UI потоке запускается, то сначала цикл полностью отработает, а уже после этого ваш интерфейс перерисуется, потому вы видите уже конечный результат без промежуточных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как верно замечено - "сначала цикл полностью отработает, а уже после этого ваш интерфейс перерисуется".

Это должно было быть просто.

Заведите поле с массивом статусов

```
private string[] statuses;
```

затем где-нибудь однократно загрузите их, не надо обновлять их на каждый клик

```
statuses = context.Statuses.Select(x => x.Statusname).ToArray();
```

Затем переключайтесь по ним

```
private int currentStatus;

private void SwitchStatus()
{
    currentStatus = (currentStatus + 1) % statuses.Length;
}
```

Ну и в методе `dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick` вызывайте фильтр так

```
FilterStatus(statuses[currentStatus]);
```

Массив статусов следует обновлять каждый раз после изменения данных.

Comment: Извините за вопрос, но зачем в конце вычисления переменной currentStatus currentStatus = (currentStatus + 1) **% statuses.Length;**

Comment: @KuroIsekai вы же знаете, что делает `%`? Сколько будет `4 % 5`? А `5 % 5`?

Comment: это понятно)Просто при отработке второго прохода, меня выкидывает в другое событие, и я пытаюсь понять почему.